# Re-enabling Grub 2 entry after having removed it with grub-customize

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

At the beginning my computer was equipped with Windows 10 that was installed on a SSD C:/ and had it's data on a 1 Tb D:/ .
I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 64bits on the D:/ hardrive. I then changed the boot order so ubuntu would come before windows and open GRUB where I could chose between it and windows.

But I wanted Windows to boot by default so I installed **grub-customizer** on my Ubuntu. I don't know how but like an idiot I removed the Windows 10 entry (which I only discovered at the next boot). So now my only way of switching between both OS is to open the Boot Loader and change the OS that should launch first, which isn't very convenient.

I'd like to know how I could re-enable that entry. I've tried updating GRUB but it didn't change anything (output down below).

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

I was thinking about reinstalling it but it seemed a bit extreme, I was wondering if there was a smarter way of doing it.

Comment: Try running `update-grub` with root or sudo. Reboot and should of fixed it.

Comment: I did but it didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: Ah sorry, my eyes must of missed that when reading earlier. I did that to fix it when I ran into your issue of removing a entry. Cannot help you any further sorry.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo update-grub`. Does it show your Windows installation?

Comment: Done,  I might be wrong but I think it doesn't find Windows. I'll try your solution and see if it works.

Comment: Ah, no, if it doesn't find Windows, my suggestion won't make any difference. Are you sure there is a Windows installation there? Have you tried mounting the Windows `C:` drive and examining the contents?

Comment: The windows exists, but it is on `/dev/sdb3`. At one point I had both choice on the GRUB.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Repair](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? That should provide more information on how Windows’ boot loader is configured and why it might not be picked up by Grub. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `update-grub` script will create a new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. This is the basic configuration file for the GRUB bootloader. However, updating the file is not enough, the relevant files need to be copied to `/boot/grub` and, depending on your system (probably not, in your case, since you're almost certainly using an EFI system), GRUB might also need to be installed to the master boot record. In any case, you need to also run `grub-install`. So, run these commands and then reboot:

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

**Important**: make sure to change `/dev/sda` to whichever device you have GRUB installed on. You *probably* have it on `/dev/sda` since that's the first hard drive.

Comment: Should I specify the partition? (my `/` is on `/dev/sda3`).

Comment: @ashtrail no, just `/dev/sda`.